# MSYS2 and libcurl, which libs to link?

Tags: libcurl, mingw-w64, msys2

I am having some big headaches linking statically libcurl in MSYS2 mingw.
I installed libcurl and all the listed dependencies from here

https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-curl

Since I am using CodeBlocks as IDE I need to supply a whole list of libs in form of lib#?.a, please keep in mind that I know nothing of Linux world and gcc tools and command line, otherwise I wouldn't be using an IDE!

Also I am not skilled enough to compile lib packages. I just need to write some portable code to do a https post request in cpp, so I need libcurl.

Can you tell me a complete list of all the needed libs to link against ? I tried all my best but I keep getting an infinity of unresolved symbols

UPDATE

After having checked what the package config for libcurl says, I have installed all the missing libs and used the following command line:

g++.exe  -o MyProg.exe obj\Release\main.o  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -m64 -lcurl -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lssh2 -lpsl -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lzstd -lbrotlidec -lz -lws2_32 -s

Despite that I am still getting tons of undefined references:

d:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libcurl.a(gsasl.o):(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `gsasl_init'

[plus many other 'gsasl...' referrences]

d:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../lib\libbrotlidec.a(decode.c.o):(.text+0x2d28): undefined reference to `BrotliTransformDictionaryWord'

[plus many other 'brotli...' references]

Comment: I suggest you use [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib). It's portable and header only library, no custom linker steps are required. Unless you want to enable https support.

Comment: @273K sadly I am forced to have HTTPS support :(

Comment: If you focused on HTTPS, then you will apply the same options after libcurl.

Answer (score 1):

`pkg-config` will tell you the necessary flags. Install it from the package `mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`.

Run it as `pkg-config --libs --static libcurl`.

Copy the output into "linker flags -> other". For me the output is `-L/mingw64/lib -lcurl -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lssh2 -lpsl -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lzstd -lbrotlidec -lz -lws2_32`. Don't forget to add the `--static` flag, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Thanks HolyBlackCat... that was actually what I already did by looking at what the package config says. Unfortunately it does not work, I keep getting undefined references. I really don't know what I am still doing wrong. This is my command line:
g++.exe  -o Workbench.exe obj\Release\main.o  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -m64 -lcurl -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lssh2 -lpsl -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lzstd -lbrotlidec -lz -lws2_32 -s.               I am not allowed to post the full output because it is too long sadly

Comment: @elena The output you posted hints that you have some other MinGW version installed, which somehow interferes. Remove it. Also, I believe `-m64` is unnecessary (`MINGW64` compiler defaults to 64 bits), and so are `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc` (they're implied by `-static`).

Comment: #HolyBlackCat thanks for your patience. Those flags are set by Code::Blocks, however I removed them and I just left -static, no hope. Re: some other MinGW version, that is unlike since I am using a freshly installed MSYS2 and my IDE points to its mingw64 dir only and nothing else...

Comment: @elena Then what's in `d:/mingw64_prev`?

Comment: That's just how I called a backup folder while doing experiments. It makes no difference. BTW I think I am understanding what it's up. It really looks like the package config fails to list the dependences of dependences !!! In fact I also had to link against libbrotlicommon.a and some undefined reference errors went away. But there are so many that figuring out all the sub deps of deps is going to be a nightmare

Comment: OK It looks like in the end I did it :) Yes I was right... the .pc simply was not listing deps of deps so I had to find them down by hand (ok and by luck). Here is the whole list of the needed libs: -lcurl -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lssh2 -lpsl -ladvapi32 -lcrypt32 -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lwldap32 -lzstd -lbrotlidec -lz -lws2_32 -lbrotlicommon -lunistring -liconv :) Sadly I fear this is much relative to the version of libcurl I am using and things may vary between different versions and in future (I am no expert here)

Comment: @elena I could swear it worked for me yesterday, but apparently I tested it incorrectly; I do reproduce the problem. Apparently it's already [been reported](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/3538). Though I would remove `d:/mingw64_prev`, since it shouldn't appear in the output at all. At least remove it from the PATH.

Comment: Sorry for those confusing _prev, I removed them in the main question

Comment: @elena `d:/mingw64/bin` is equally confusing, since it doesn't look like a MSYS2 installation. MSYS2 would look like `d:/some_path/mingw64/bin`. Generally, you shouldn't artifically modify output, a wrong change could cause confusion.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is not my fault. I am fixing it. Another important detail (unfortunately I am not allowed to edit the comment again), I also have to define CURL_STATICLIB. Now the example program compiles and links fine but I am having issues with certificates ->[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312185/libcurl-curl-easy-perform-fails-problem-with-the-ssl-ca-cert-path-access)